# How do I get JavaScript to show up in an editor?

Tags: javascript, editor, jsfiddle

I'm using codecademy to learn JavaScript and I wanted to test some of my own for loops in an editor (currently using jsfiddle).

This is the very simple code I put in to the JavaScript section.

```
for (var i = 4; i < 24; i = i + 1) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

In codecademy's lesson, it gives me a list. Nothing shows up in jsfiddle when I hit run, however.

How does one make their JavaScript run in an editor?

Comment: Open up the console window in the browser. Most browsers use F12 to open up developer tools, where you can choose the console.

Comment: In Chrome (at least on OS X), it's `<Command> + <Option> + J`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can open the console, using F12 or an equivalent. You can also use a custom logging function that creates or uses a `div` to write the result to:

Basically something like:

```
function log(str) {
  var logdiv = document.querySelector('#result');
  if (!logdiv) {
    logdiv = document.createElement('div');
    logdiv.id = 'result';
    document.body.appendChild(logdiv);
  }
  logdiv.innerHTML += '<p>'+str+'</p>';
}
```

And your loop can use that:

```
for (var i = 4; i < 24; i = i + 1) {
    log(i);
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oad3va7h/)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` doesn't print to a page, rather it prints to the console.  You can access the console with the following shortcuts:

- **Firefox**: `Ctrl+Shift+K`
- **Chrome**: `Ctrl+Shift+J`
- **Safari**: `Command+Option+C`
- **Opera**: Recent versions don't support this out of the box, but it is available in the Dragonfly extension.